# Java Array Trouble

Tags: java, arrays, opengl

I have 4 terrains (landscapes) and they each have a coord in the world. But I can not seem to get which terrain the player's x & z coords are in. Here is what I have.
This is the constructor that is run every time a Terrain is made. Each time, the terrain being created is added the the Terrain[][].

```
    public static Terrain[][] terrains;

    public Terrain(int gridX, int gridZ, Loader loader, TerrainTexturePack texturePack, TerrainTexture blendMap, String heightMap) {
        this.texturePack = texturePack;
        this.blendMap = blendMap;
        this.x = gridX * SIZE;
        this.z = gridZ * SIZE;
        this.model = generateTerrain(loader, heightMap);
        terrains[(int) (gridX)][(int) (gridZ)] = this;
    }
```

I use this to get the terrain of the player's current x and z.

```
Terrain.terrains[(int) ((int) player.getPosition().x/Terrain.getSize())][(int) ((int) player.getPosition().z/Terrain.getSize())]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What is getSize? Why all the casts?

Comment: getSize gets the size of the terrain's edge. So currently it's 800. All the casts bc IDE's told me to haha.